# Help with defined by me command

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols

I defined a \newcommand as follows:

```
\newcommand{\boxup}{\ooalign{$\Box$\cr\hss\raisebox{0ex}{\scriptsize $\shortuparrow$}\hss}}
```

It is a box with arrow inside it.

Then I want to use it in the math mode with a regular box \Box. 
If I write it as `$\Box\boxup$` I get nice equal sized boxes.

[image]

Then I write the same as `K_{\Box\boxup}`
and get

[image]

the inequal sized boxes.
Here is preamble of my file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{easychair}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newcommand{\boxfut}{\ooalign{$\Box$\cr\hss\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scriptsize $\shortrightarrow$}\hss}}
\newcommand{\boxpast}{\ooalign{$\Box$\cr\hss\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scriptsize $\shortleftarrow$}\hss}}
\newcommand{\diafut}{\ooalign{$\Diamond$\cr\hss\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scriptsize $\shortrightarrow$}\hss}}
\newcommand{\diapast}{\ooalign{$\Diamond$\cr\hss\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scriptsize $\shortleftarrow$}\hss}}
\newcommand{\diaup}{\ooalign{$\Diamond$\cr\hss\raisebox{0ex}{\scriptsize $\shortuparrow$}\hss}}
\newcommand{\boxup}{\ooalign{$\Box$\cr\hss\raisebox{0ex}{\scriptsize $\shortuparrow$}\hss}}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,graphicx}
```

Would someone suggest me how to adjust the error?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete MWE. Your code snippet can't be compiled.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you cited all the packages you're using. I've got the solution, but without the appropriate packages, the document just won't compile.

Comment: I want the arrow to be in the box. 
I made an edit, and add the preamble

Comment: @kampa I changed 0pt by 0.2pt It looks like best, but problem is in size of boxes not in arrow I gues, Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not easy to get the measurements right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\boxup}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathbin or \mathrel
    \vphantom{\Box}%
    \text{\kuzne@box\shortuparrow}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\boxfut}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathbin or \mathrel
    \vphantom{\Box}%
    \text{\kuzne@box\shortrightarrow}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\boxpast}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathbin or \mathrel
    \vphantom{\Box}%
    \text{\kuzne@box\shortleftarrow}%
  }%
}

\newsavebox{\kuzne@box@box}
\newsavebox{\kuzne@box@base}
\newlength{\kuzne@box@raise}
\newcommand{\kuzne@box}[1]{%
  \sbox\kuzne@box@base{$\m@th\Box$}%
  \sbox\kuzne@box@box{$\m@th\text{\check@mathfonts\raisebox{-\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$#1$}}$}%
  \kuzne@box@raise=.5\dimexpr\ht\kuzne@box@base+\dp\kuzne@box@base\relax
  \ooalign{%
    \box\kuzne@box@base\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{\kuzne@box@raise}{\box\kuzne@box@box}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Box\boxup\boxfut\boxpast_{\Box\boxup\boxfut\boxpast_{\Box\boxup\boxfut\boxpast}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code for `\diafut` and `\diapast` (doesn't work in second level subscripts); add it between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\newcommand{\diafut}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathbin or \mathrel
    \vphantom{\Diamond}%
    \text{\kuzne@dia\shortrightarrow}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\diapast}{%
  \mathord{% or \mathbin or \mathrel
    \vphantom{\Diamond}%
    \text{\kuzne@dia\shortleftarrow}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\kuzne@dia}[1]{%
  \sbox\kuzne@box@base{$\m@th\Diamond$}%
  \sbox\kuzne@box@box{$\m@th\text{\check@mathfonts\raisebox{-\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}$}%
  \kuzne@box@raise=.45\dimexpr\ht\kuzne@box@base+\dp\kuzne@box@base\relax
  \ooalign{%
    \box\kuzne@box@base\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{\kuzne@box@raise}{\box\kuzne@box@box}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
```

Here's the output for `$\diafut\diapast_{\diafut\diapast}$`

[image]